# How to write a htaccess rewrite rule to get links like this?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like a rewrite rule to have the following behavior.

If the URL is:

```
/users
```

it would rewrite with index.php?template=users

And if it's:

```
/users?id=2
```

it would rewrite with index.php?template=users&id=2 for however many variables are in the URL. So that means that even if i used

```
/users?id=2&action=edit&something=no&something_else=yes
```

i'd want all of those variables to be passed, thus getting /index.php?template=usersid=2&action=edit&something=no&something_else=yes

---

Until now, my htaccess rule has always been:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php?template=$1
```

But with that, i cannot use URL's with a question mark in them like i'd want to. Instead, i'd have to use /users&id=2, which looks silly.

I have googled quite a bit, but the solutions either don't work, or aren't similar enough to my case for me to adapt them and get what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the `QSA` flag, query string append which will add the rest of the query string to the redirect rule if you have more parameters:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?template=$1 [QSA,L]
```